# How to catch an IOException for reset() method?

Tags: java, exception

I'm writing this code and I keep getting a runtime error telling me I need to catch the IOException. How do I do that? This is my code:

```
System.out.println( "\nThese presidents were born before the states were formed:\n");  // DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY
    ArrayList<String> america = new ArrayList<String>();
    String l;
    String line;
    while((line = infile2.readLine()) != null) 
    {

        america.add(line);
    }
    Collections.sort(america);
    infile1.reset();
    try
    {
        while((infile1.ready()))
        {
            ArrayList<String> am = new ArrayList<String>();
            l= infile1.readLine();
            String [] ls = l.split(" ");
            for(int i=1; i<ls.length;i++)
            {
                am.add(ls[i]);
            }
            Collections.sort(am);
            america.removeAll(am);
        }
    }
    catch( IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }

    System.out.println(america);
```

Comment: In general, it's a great idea to show us the stack traces/error output you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting a compilation error instead not a runtime error.

The line `while((line = infile2.readLine()) != null)` contains a call to a method that can throw `IOException` but you haven't wrapped it with `try-catch`.

Possibly same problem with the `infile1.reset()` call there.

The reason for this is that in Java, exceptions are checked; if a method you're calling declares `throws FooException`, you either need to wrap calls to that method with `try { ... } catch(FooException e) { ... }` or mark the calling method with `throws FooException` (or any exception up in the exception hierarchy).